# App launcher icon issue while building the app

Tags: flutter, appicon

```
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > Android resource compilation failed
        ERROR:AAPT: C:\Users\Prejith T S\Documents\projects\ATTENDANCE\TASKT7\wtiattendance\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
        C:\Users\Prejith T S\Documents\projects\ATTENDANCE\TASKT7\wtiattendance\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: file failed to compile.
```

i want to build an apk for my client but now it is not possible

Answer (score 2):

It's likely a JPG renamed to a PNG file, not an actual PNG file
The problem could be because of the wrong extension of images.

The file was a JPE image but it was saved as PNG not converted to. In this situation change extension to the real one and convert to PNG then retry.

For instance, you have `ic_launcher.png` but it's actually a JPG image.
You should rename it back to `ic_launcher.jpg` and use something like Photoshop, or online convert tools to convert the image to PNG format.

Comment: thanks a lot. in my case i used a jpg image. and convert this jpg to png by using online convertor.